# Sharing edits in shared shared commits in git

Tags: git, sharing, rebase, git-rebase, updating

Git allows you to edit history of the branch with `git rebase -interactive`. You can edit some commit, which worth updating for other branches also. How do you update another branch?

For instance, I had two branches A=`Root <- A1 <- A2 <-A3` and B=`Root <- B2 <- B3`. Now, I edited interactively first one, updating `Root => Root1`. How do I rebase branch B to Root1 instead of the `Root`, how do I tell it that Root1 is a new version of Root? I am asking because rebasing B to Root commit to stay on top of Roo1. Definitely, it is not what I want.

Here is the code to reproduce the situation

```
mkdir shared_commit_update ; cd shared_commit_update

git init; git checkout -b Init ; echo iii > init ; git add init ; git commit -m init ; 

git checkout -b Root ; echo rrr > root ; git add root ; git commit -m root

git checkout -b Top ; echo toptop > top ; git add top ; git commit -m top

git checkout Root ; git checkout -b UpdatedRoot ; echo 222 > root ; git add root ; git commit --amend -m updated_root

git checkout Top ; echo Try to replace tops root with updated root ; gitk --all & 
bash

echo 'shared_commit_update' folder created
```

I want `Top` commit to be located upon `UpdatedRoot` one. If I just do `git rebase UpdatedRoot` I will get `UpdatedRoot` on the top of `Root` instead of in place of it.

Answer (score 0):

You switch to to branch B (that is `git checkout B`). Then, rebase on using the hash of the commit Root1 (that is `git rebase -i [hash of Root1]`)

Comment: I am getting `Root1` upon `Root` with interactive option also.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use [--onto option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase). I have achieved the goal with

```
 git rebase --onto UpdatedRoot Root Top
```

It will detach Top from Root and transplant it on top of UpdatedRoot instead.